# Python - Get Devices Connected to Computer

Tags: python, windows, device

Is there any library for Python that I can use to find all the devices that are connected to the computer? I know you can do something similar in C# and identify the USBs for Python but what about all the devices? I am using **Windows 8**.

Comment: I don't use windows but I suspect there is a command you can put into the commandline to get this info. Perhaps something like `msinfo32 /report myinfo.txt` which you can call with os.system or subprocess modules; then just read the created file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the pywinusb lib

But I think that it is a bit complex

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinusb/

Maybe you can get it with pip

```
pip install pywinusb
```